# How is it possible to filter on `author` or `sender` using Python exchangelib v 4.5.1?

Tags: python, filtering, exchangelib

Using exchangelib's django-like syntax, I can successfully filter() on a message's `subject` field:

```
my_account.inbox.filter(subject__contains="foo")
```

But I've found no way to do (and no examples of) a filter() on `sender` or `author`. Since `author` (for example) is a `Mailbox` object with a `name` field, I expected this, or some variant on it to work:

```py
my_account.inbox.filter(author__name="Foo")
```

But it fails with an error like this:

```py
exchangelib.fields.InvalidField: Unknown field path 'author__name' on folders 
[Messages(Root(<exchangelib.account.Account object at 0x0000020561F64308>, ....
```

Variants like `sender__name__eq`, `sender__email_address`, etc. fared no better.

I've also tried an undecorated `sender`. Using `sender` doesn't give an error, but it never seems to match anything (at least not the `name` or `email_address` fields).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The logic for filtering on the `author` and `sender` fields in EWS are a bit weird. There's a long explanation at https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues/913. The main part to take away is:

- You cannot filter on subfields of `sender`. `sender__name` and `sender__email` cannot be referenced in a filter expression in EWS
- `sender__icontains` filter works as expected when `mailbox_type='OneOff'`, not `mailbox_type='Mailbox'`
- using an AQS query string like `.filter('from:"somedomain.com"')` works as expected for both OneOff and Mailbox mailbox types